# How many labels are defined in ARINC 429 for calibrated altitude?

Tags: avionics, arinc-429

How many labels are defined in ARINC 429 for calibrated altitude?

Comment: What Equipment ID are you interested in?

Comment: I dont know it.................

Comment: Are you trying to decode an ARINC label or figure out what label to send the data as or something else? By "calibrated" to mean baro corrected?

Comment: I find out what is the Arinc label for calibrated alt data?

Comment: In my copy of ARINC 429 (2004), there is no label defined for "calibrated altitude". There are labels defined for [Pressure] Altitude (1013.2 mbar) and Baro Corrected Altitude. What exactly are you trying to indicate?

Answer (score 4):

There is no defined "calibrated altitude". 
The following are all altitude related labels:

- 102 Selected Altitude,
- 107 Selected Cruise Altitude,
- 120 Range to Altitude,
- 127 Selected Landing Altitude,
- 131 Intruder Altitude,
- 144 Altitude Error,
- 153 Max Altitude,
- 162 Density Altitude,
- 164 Min Descent Altitude (MDA),
- 203 Altitude,
- 204 Baro Corrected Altitude #1 & Baro Altitude,
- 206 Altitude (Variable Resolution),
- 212 Altitude Rate,
- 220 Baro Corrected Altitude #2,
- 225 Compensated Altitude Rate,
- 251 Baro Corrected Altitude #3,
- 252 Baro Corrected Altitude #4,
- 254 Altitude Rate,
- 323 Geometric Altitude,
- 361 Altitude (Inertial)

Answer (score 0):

In ARINC 429 a label refers to a parameter, for instance AOA (angle of attack). When you have several sensors for the same parameter, the same label is used for all sensors but 2 additional digits (SDI, Source Destination Identifier) are used to distinguish them, for instance left AOA and right AOA.

As a summary, a parameter can't use several labels but the same label might refer to similar parameters from different sources or sensors.